# how to pass php variable to charge create in stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have successfully integrated stripe payment. However, when I pass hardcoded amount and currency it works fine, but as I use variable in the charge array it gives me `HTTP ERROR 500`

My code:

```
 <?php
require_once "config.php";
session_start();
$depoamount=$_SESSION['stripeamount'];
$curr=$_SESSION['curr'];
$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
$custid=$_SESSION['reg_no'];
//$custid='123';
$id=$_POST['ID'];
/* $depoamount=1200;
$curr='inr';*/
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
  'email' => $email,
  'source'  => $token,
  'customer'=> $custid,

]);

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'customer' => $customer->id,
  'amount'   => $depoamount,// If I use '5000' it works
  'currency' => $curr,// same if I put 'usd' it works
 ]);

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged</h1>';
  echo $charge->email;
  echo $charge->id;
  echo $custid;
 ?>
```

I think syntax is ok , however its not working.

Comment: What are the values of `$depoamount` and `$curr`?

Comment: these are coming from previous page, its user input value

Comment: What are their values when you get the error? Try `var_dump($demoamount);var_dump($curr);`.

Comment: in charge array I put `'amount'   => $depoamount,` it gives error and if I put `'amount'   => '5000',` works fine

Comment: page is not loading `kaem.in is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: that what my concern is, I thought may be SESSION might not be working hence i hard coded it to test `$depoamount=5000` but still it shows error

Comment: I tried `$depoamount='5000'` still the sam e

Comment: You may want to check server error logs and try [outputting PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/924299).

Comment: I am on shared hosting, so `display_errors = on` would be difficult

Comment: Try `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Is the `$_SESSION` populated? You might get an error like "Undefined index: stripeamount".

Comment: If you're getting an error from the API server, there's probably not much we can do for you. Have you asked the API maintainers why your requests are failing?

Comment: @miken32 "kaem.in" doesn't sound like a Stripe server. I think it's the OP's server, but I could be wrong.

Comment: So, using `'amount' => 5000` works, and `'amount' => '5000'` works, but setting `$depoamount = 5000;` and then `'amount' => $depoamount` doesn't work?

Comment: `'amount' => '5000'` this works but `$depoamount = 5000;` and then `'amount' => $depoamount` this doesnt

Comment: @GregSchmidt  guided me to think on line of string , so I converted `$depoamount=(string)$depoamount;` now its working